# Passing selected folder path to custom Service executing AppleScript

Tags: macos, automator, applescript, shortcut-menu, services

I have a custom Service I created in Automator. Right now, the service shows up in my context (right-click) menu, when right-clicking on any folder. In Automator, I added the Run AppleScript action, to execute this code:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    do shell script "/usr/bin/find ./ -type f -name .DS_Store -delete -print"
    return input
end run
```

My objective is to delete all `.DS_Store` files in the selected folder (and all folders within it). I normally do this in Terminal by executing `/usr/bin/find /path-to-folder -type f -name .DS_Store -delete -print`, but I would love to get this to work from my custom Service.

I'm thinking I need to pass the selected folders path to the AppleScript function (through `input` perhaps?), but I have no idea how, nor do I see any actions in Automator to pass this. I'm using OS X 10.6.5. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of the screen, above your action, there should be a list-box that says `Service receives selected <text> in <any application>`.  Changing `<text>` to `folders` should give you the folders as `input`.

Comment: Thank you. That's it. You wouldn't happen to also know how to convert the path it passes `Macintosh HD:Users:Matthew:Documents:Programming:Apple Scripts:` to a path like `Macintosh\ HD/Users/Matthew/Documents/Programming/Apple\ Scripts`?

Comment: @matthewpavkov: unfortunately no... but there might be a command line utility.  feel free to create another question, I'm sure someone around here knows :P

Comment: @matthewpavkov In Applescript, `posix path of (Classic:Style:Path:)` will return a  posix path.